# Grid column span total width - 1?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is there anyway to tell my `gp1` class column to start at grid position 1 and **end at position max - 1**, bearing in mind this is a dynamic grid?

```css
.widthContainer {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#eee;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 25px);
  min-height: 98%;
}

.grid>div {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25px, 1fr));
  display: grid;
}

.gp1 {
  background-color: #aaa;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start:2;
  grid-column-end:4;
}
```

```html
<div class="widthContainer">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="bkg">
      <div class="gp1">
        <div>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are already doing it with `grid-column: 1/-1;` so use `grid-column: 2/-2;`

Comment: Oh THAT'S what that is doing, shorthand for start/end FFS. Still learning css-grid - I'd read that somewhere and it had just skipped my mind because I was so wrapped up in all the wrappers.

Comment: grid-column: 1/-2;* ("start at grid position 1 and end at position max - 1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `-2` for `grid-column-end`

```css
.widthContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 25px);
  min-height: 98%;
}

.grid>div {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/-1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25px, 1fr));
  display: grid;
}

.gp1 {
  background-color: #aaa;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="widthContainer">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="bkg">
      <div class="gp1">
        <div>
          <p>content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lol - so simple. I was even trying `Calc(none - 1)` and all variations of `max - 1` I could think of ... DOH!

Comment: @jamheadart if was helpful please accept the answer

Comment: Sorry, I tried earlier and it was too soon. Just got back online now to accept.